# How to set different widths for elements within the same container element in Singularity

Tags: css, singularitygs

I am still puzzled about a few certain aspects in the application of Singularity. I wonder for example about one thing. In the following gist i have set up a few simple elements. The blue at the bottom is the footer, the yellow in the middle the content and the upper three cells (red, green fuchsia - built by grid-span) build the header. All three parts are build by the same container.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/8010028

I wonder what would be the cleanest approach to make the header broader than the other two.

- By defining a width in percentage just for the wrapping header element?
- By applying the layout mixin to the header element and set a whole new context?

Or is it even impossible to have different width for one of the three if they all rely onto the same container settings and context? Best regards Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singularity is container-agnostic, so you can position your header container in any way that you prefer.

There are many ways to make one of containers larger, and this problem is not related to Singularity.

My favorite method is negative margins. It is not applicable to your styles because you set `margin: 0 auto` on your containers. I suggest that you use `margin: 0 auto` on `body` instead. This will require some refactoring.

What does relate to Singularity though is the problem of maintaining a consistent grid throughout containers of different widths. You'll need to do some math and spend some time fiddling with values.

Here's what i managed to achieve: http://sassbin.com/gist/8030219/

Note that i'm not using the `layout` mixin but simply redefine `$grids`. This method is not recommended but is acceptable when there are several different grids and none of them can be called the main one.

PS Note that SassMeister is on Sass 3.3 whereas Singularity and Breakpoint aren't behaving properly on Sass 3.3. Use SassBin.com instead which stays on Sass 3.2.

Comment: Wow nice one! Thanks! Ok Haml and plain Sass makes things a bit trickier but i think i understand it anyway. ^^ And the recommended approach would be via the layout mixin? Instead of reassigning $grids it would be recommended to use the layout mixin? But the broadening of the, in your case main container class, with negative margins and doing the base sizing definition in the body is the recommended way?

Comment: Haml and Sass are much easier to read once you grasp the syntax. Use the `layout` mixin if you've got a site-wide grid that you would like to override. Override `$grids` if you come up with a different grid for every use. There's no recommended way for setting up your containers. It is a matter of personal preference and experience.

Comment: hmmmm but two more questions arose. Your solution works fine but if you take the setting of my initial example in consideration i've used background colors. one for the mainwrap which contains the header element as well as the main element and the footwrap containing the footer. the footer wrapper has a background color and wrapper for header and main content another. with your solution the background color wouldn't fill the whole width of the background or if you use an image as background pattern that neither. at least as far as i can understand it. :/

Comment: The other question might sound a bit dumb but since there isn't an explicit container mixin in Singularity it's still a bit abstract to me since i guess the name "container" isn't mandatory that Singularity knows what the container is (I was used to Susys @include container; ). Especially in your sassbin example the container class doesn't hold any important properties aside the clearfix.

Comment: So does it mean that the container element is normally the parent element of a child where one of the grid spanning mixins like gutter-span, float-span etc gets applied? So we could have renamed the container classes individually to e.g. .cnt-header, .cnt-main, .cnt-footer or  all of them to e.g. .banana ( to take an abstruse example ) instead of .container. ;)

Comment: ok about my first question i think i found a workaround to make things work in my initial gist: http://sassmeister.com/gist/8010028 (updated version) i set the containers max-width to the width of the broadest container. the others i could narrow down with the width property. as done with div.container width: 50%. Tried that before but had forgotten that the width refers to the width of the window viewport instead of the container. so a width of 80% hasn't done anything. reason 80% of the whole viewport was still broader than the max-width of 750px so no visible change - now it changes. ;)

Comment: Hey @rpk, this discussion has gone beyond the StackOverflow format which is supposed to be dedicated to a single specific problem. Feel free to message me at Hangouts lolmaus@gmail.com or Skype lolmaus_ and we'll work on a solution.

Comment: @lolmaus sorry for the delay but i had no computer access over the last 1,5 weeks. And you are right, basically my initial question contains all the different aspects but it is way beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question. at the moment i have to deal with some basic gem issues in relation with codekit. but before those turned up i already figured most of my remaining questions. But when i get things going smoothly again i would be more than happy to drop you a line. Thanks a lot!